# Use macro for iOS Unit Test

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, ios-simulator, xctest

I am writing test cases for my camera application.

For instance, I want to provide a mock object when the tests are running in Simulator. I could not use macro to run the corresponding code like this:

```
    #if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
    vc.camera = mockCamera
    #endif
```

What is the better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot test if the app is running in test via macro. You can test it in runtime via `NSProcessInfo`:

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment]["XCInjectBundle"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I check the folder name for difference? As I spotted `Debug-iphonesimulator` and `Debug-iphoneos`

Comment: Only when it is testing ``XCInjectBundle`` will have values, so you just need to check if it has non nil value.

Comment: My case is to run both simulator and device in testing, and I want to differentiate between them.

Comment: Well you can combine the macro approach, or maybe check the bundle path as you suggested then. Personally I'd create helper methods such as App.isTestBundle(), App.isSimulator() ... etc to help, which would better than mess with lots of macro.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will stay with the current approach. Helper class is definitely helpful and clean too.